# How to replace characters at the start of a string and specific locations within it?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a function that creates a string of zeros and ones (0's and 1's) separated by commas.
I need to remove the commas. I have the code for this.

I need to count the amount of 0's at the beginning of the string, before a number 1 is encountered and store the amount of 0's as say, tmpstr1. *Code needed*.

There is a maximum of six 0's. There is a minimum of no 0's (the string may already start with a 1).

Then from the beginning of the string, count forward 112 characters, then the next characters in the string, the amount equal to tmpstr1, should then be converted to 0's (even if they already are 0's it is okay to convert).
*code needed*

*All the rest of the code I can get from the code supplied above*.

What will then happen is:
From the beginning of the string, count forward 119 spaces, then the next characters in the string, the amount equal to tmpstr1, should then be converted to 0's.
Moving forward 7 characters each time. Repeat until the end of the string, which is 203 characters in length.
If two 0's were removed from the start of the string, characters 113 and 114 would be the first 2 characters replaced, and so on......
If it were three 0's removed from the start of the string, characters 113, 114 and 115 would be the first 3 charters replaced, and so on......

I have the final code to remove the leading 0's, but am stumped for the rest of it.
Lots of examples to find characters in a string but not just at the beginning before another character is encountered.
Likewise with replace. Nothing for just 'n' characters at specific locations.

Okay, I now have the first part (finding amount of leading 0's). Code modified below:

This is the code so far:

```
  for(var row= 0, rowStates=[]; row<rowsCount; ++row){
    rowStates = sheetStates[row];
    timesheetrowsdata += rowStates+(row==rowsCount?'':',');
  }

  //Remove the commas
  timesheetcoldata = timesheetrowsdata.replace(/,/g, '');

  var tmpstr1 = timesheetcoldata.search(/1/);

  //code here to replace the first round of characters.
  //code here to replace the second round of characters.
  //and so on.......

  //  strip any leading 0's
      while(timesheetcoldata.charAt(0) === '0'){
      timesheetcoldata = timesheetcoldata.substr(1);
    }
```

This is an example string due for replacement (with 3 leading 0's):

```
00010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010001111000111100011110001111000111000011100001110000111000011100001110000000000000000000000000
```

With characters 113, 114, 115 and so on ........ all replaced:

```
00010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Finally the leading zeros removed:

```
10000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly the code you are looking for is something like this:

```js
var sourceString = '00010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010001111000111100011110001111000111000011100001110000111000011100001110000000000000000000000000';

function recode(s) {
 // i'll try to create an easy to follow piece of code, so some logic is deliberately "old fashioned"
  
  // phase 1, determine number of leading zeroes
  var countLeadingZeroes = 0;
  while (s[countLeadingZeroes] == 0)
  {
   countLeadingZeroes += 1;
  }
  var amountNonReplaced = 7 - countLeadingZeroes
  
  // phase 2, skip 112 chars, and start replaceing <countLeadingZeroes> every 7 chars
  var startIdx = 112
  w = s.slice(0,startIdx);
  
  while (startIdx < 203) {
  
    for (var i = 0; i<countLeadingZeroes;i++) {
      w += '0'
      startIdx += 1;
    }
    for (var i =0; i<amountNonReplaced;i++) {
      w += s.slice(startIdx,startIdx+1);
      startIdx += 1;
    }
  }
  return w;
}

alert(recode(sourceString));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Christiaan. You understood me correctly. This is all I need and so much more. Works exactly as I was hoping, but I never expected to have it working so soon. Amazing!

Comment: This is working well. I have a further use for it. How could i do the same thing but remove 0's and 1's instead of just zeros?

Comment: Its OK, I figured out out. Thanks again.